# Dapper LIKE query for MySql safe against Sql Injection?

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

Is this query safe against sql injection in combination with Dapper? 
If not, what would be the correct way to write it under MySql? 
Or is there a better version without using concat?

```
string sql = "SELECT * from user_profile WHERE FirstName LIKE CONCAT("%",@name,"%");"
var result = connection.query<profile>(sql, new {name});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **safe** because you are **not building SQL dynamically at all**. Name is just a normal parameter. Actually, it has nothing to do with Dapper.

Using a string concat here is the right choice. Alternatively you could use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function.

Answer (score 18):

There isn't a problem with that code, but another approach is to perform the the concat at the caller, i.e.

```
const string sql = "SELECT * from user_profile WHERE FirstName LIKE @name;";
var result = connection.Query<Profile>(sql, new {name = "%"+name+"%"});
```

Comment: This works but provides the sever with less information about the structure of the pattern. Not sure if this matters for substring searches but it definitely does for starts-with searches.

Comment: @usr it would be interesting to profile that.  It doesn't impact some other RDBMS in a negative way.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers!